# Powershell Get-Service to show all services executed with specific service account name

Tags: windows, powershell

How to sort the services under windows 2012r2 with powershell to show only ones executed with service account "...name..." In the enterprise domain environment

Answer (score 1):

You can do that by querying the WMI `Win32_Service` class using the [Get-WmiObject](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee176860.aspx) cmdlet.

For example, this will retrieve all the Windows Services that run under the `LocalSystem` account:

```
Get-WmiObject -Query "select name, startname from Win32_Service where startname = 'LocalSystem'"
```

Alternatively, you can retrieve all Windows Services from WMI and filter them in PowerShell using:

```
Get-WmiObject Win32_Service | where StartName -eq "LocalSystem"
```

Comment: Thanks going to test it now and will let you know